# What happened to the answers and bounty I placed on my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

So recently I asked this question: [Difference between intersection and merged types `{ foo } & { bar }` and `{ foo, bar }` in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61330455/4135063)

It didn't get much attention so I placed a bounty of 50 on it.

When the bounty was almost over someone showed up and added two answers, that looked good, I am pretty sure I even upvoted both. However, I did not have time to look into it in detail until now.

Today I opened the question and to my surprise there is no answer there at all. I am pretty sure there were two answers. First thing I thought is that perhaps the person decided to delete both answers? But I am pretty sure upvoted answers cannot be deleted either...

Anyone know what happened (or could have happened):

- To the answers?
- To the bounty?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Upvoted answers can be deleted, there's even [a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) for it. It's *accepted* answers that can't be deleted.

Comment: Yes, I just re-checked, I don't see anything. Should I be able to see deleted answers? Somewhere in the depths of my memory I thought this was only for people with super high reputation. Perhaps the rules for one's own questions are different?

Comment: 2 by 1 person were deleted by a diamond moderator as plagiarized. Another without upvotes was deleted by its poster.

Comment: @philipxy Oh, wow. Interesting. I guess there is no way for me to look at the answers then, right? Unless I earn some more reputation?

Comment: What course of action do you suggest? Just add another bounty, perhaps?

Comment: @PedroA - You can look at the sources from where it was plagiarized. From a comment under those posts https://pawelgrzybek.com/typescript-interface-vs-type/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681316/difference-between-extending-and-intersecting-interfaces-in-typescript/52681859#52681859

Comment: Bounties time out. There has been problems with bounty placers not getting warning of end of bounty and/or grace period. It may be that notifications came & went before you checked for them. Google [help] & [meta.se]. @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You beat me to posting those links.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Awesome, thank you very much!!

Comment: Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy I think the question is already quite clear?

Comment: @JonasWilms My comment is about research before asking. It is relevant here because there isn't any research re disappearing questions & it may also be helpful re their linked post research since, although that post presents some research, there are clearly 2 relevant links the poster didn't find, yet the plagiarizer did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounty is there to get more *attention* to the post. If eligible answer added after bounty is placed than bounty will be given to such answer.

In this case the question got attention from people, but not a kind you would like

- couple 100% plagiarized answers were added
- likely moderators look at those questions too to weed out such "late completely plagiarized answers" (or just got notified by 100% plagiarized answer from SO)

As result plagiarized answers got deleted and no answers left for bounty to be assigned. So bounty is gone now (but it served its purpose also in a way that is not useful to you).

Course of actions:

- likely question is duplicate of one that was presented as an "answer" - [Difference between extending and intersecting interfaces in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681316/difference-between-extending-and-intersecting-interfaces-in-typescript/52681859#52681859), so may vote to close as such
- if that question does not answer your one - edit the post to clarify ("this link_to_answer explains ... but I'm asking for ..."). You may not need second bounty for some time while post is active on meta, but likely you'd need to add bigger (100) bounty if meta attention is not enough.
- review the second plagiarized source https://pawelgrzybek.com/typescript-interface-vs-type/ and provide self-answer based on information from both sources